# Webpack: Ignore client libraries server-side

Tags: webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to use webpack to bundle react code that gets rendered server-side and client-side. Some libs I'm trying to use (like [glidejs](https://github.com/jedrzejchalubek/Glide.js)) completely assume they are executing in the browser.

I'm not actually using the lib until componentDidMount or at some other point which won't execute on the server.

How can I require them but basically just have them do nothing in the node environment?

Glidejs specifically wants jquery, window, and document. Giving it jquery seems fine but I don't know what to do about window and document.

Comment: did you find a good solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a beautiful solution for this problem too, but – at least – there *are* two possible solutions:

1. You could bundle your node.js code with webpack by specifying [`node` as `target`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target). Then you can alias client-side code with empty stubs.
2. You can `require()` empty stubs and alias them in your webpack config to the real modules.

Comment: I've circumvented this problem in my applications by using two different entry files, one for node.js and one for the browser. But that might be impossible in some situations (especially with react).

Comment: I am using a different webpack config with `target: 'node'` but I'm not understanding how to stub the require. Do you just put an empty string for the alias like `alias: ['glidejs': '']`?

Comment: Create an empty module with a comment like `excluded by webpack` and alias this module with `'glidejs'`.